# Uploading an Image Type Application/Octet-Stream from android phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, content-type

I have a aspx page that alows a user to upload an image for their account. It tosses an error when i try to fill the form out from a android phones browser.

I wrote out the type of file my page says my phone is sending for uploading.
Its this ...  Application/Octet-Stream

How do i accept this file? I tried this code below with out sucess.

```
                        var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

                        //FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == 

                        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower() == "image/jpg" ||
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower() == "image/jpeg" ||
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower() == "image/pjpeg" ||
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower() == "image/gif" ||
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower() == "image/x-png" ||
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower() == "image/png" ||
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower() == "Application/Octet-Stream")


                        {
```

Comment: What's the error and why are you checking for content type especially if you are going to allow application/octet-stream which is basically any file, but most importantly any executable including viruses which I assume is the only reason you're checking content type in the first place...

Comment: Im trying to upload a picture from my phone.  I just get to my else statement which says you need to select a proper image type..its saying the image is of that type. Appication/Octet-Stream.

Comment: Remove the content type filter and let me know what happens.

Comment: From teh last if statement? So this code? FileUpload1.PostedFile.ToLower() == "application/octet-stream"

Comment: remove that entire if block and see what happens, or see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 to your problem is you are making a poor string comparison. The last comparison compares a lower-cased string to a string that has uppercase letters. Try this:

```
string[] sTypes = { "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/gif", "image/x-png",
    "image/png", "Application/Octet-Stream" };
bool bIsMatch = false;
foreach (string sType in sTypes)
{
    if (String.Compare(sType, FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType, true) == 0)
        bIsMatch = true;
}
if (bIsMatch)
{
    //Allow upload
}
```

Like I mentioned in your OP comments though, I really don't see the point in the content type filter if you are going to allow application/octet-stream which would allow someone to upload a virus or any other executable and a whole slew of other file types.

Comment: I dont want to allow all files just images. But when i uploaded a image from my phone its not recongized as a image. It says its of type Application/Octet-Stream. Thanks for the code above though. It would solve that issue. I need to rephrase my question properly.

Comment: No worries. Just be warned that application/octet-stream will allow people to upload executables, pdf's, and really just about any type of file. It's somewhat of an open-ended file type. If you're going to include that, I'd also recommend filtering by extension of the file as well.